# how to obtain expected value in matrix for chisqrt?

Tags: r, matrix

i want get expected value for matrix by Multiplication rowmarginal to colmarginal and divided sum of observed like folow this:

```
observed<-matrix(c(1:20),ncol=2)
expected=rowSumes*colSumes/sum(observed)
```

I want the expected value for each cell of the matrix.

Comment: Try `chisq.test(observed)$expected`

Comment: i know this function but i want understand body function to calculate expected value

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
expected = outer(rowSums(x), colSums(x), "*")/sum(x)
```